# Can I use someone else’s color scheme?

Tags: copyright, legal, licensing, trademark

I often see color themes using names of companies or products and wonder if there are potential legal issues.

For example, there are blog themes out there which replicate the look of Edward Tufte’s books and website. They may even call it “tufte-light” or “tufte-dark.” I’ve seen charting packages use the color schemes and (publicly available) font styles from The Economist or other magazines. The packages actually use the name “economist-theme” or something similar.

No one is pretending that Edward Tufte or The Economist created these (open source, non-profit) products.

I’m a developer, not a designer. But I’d like to avoid any legal or even ethical issues.

Comment: This is a **legal** question, not a design question. Better suited for http://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why bother ? Use one of those color scheme generators and make your own color combo. If you like a particular "look & feel", you can make the generator give you something similar, without copying the actual hex codes from another website.

Comment: Yes, this is a legal question, not a design question. With that said, I don't think the issue would be the color scheme; it's more using the same color scheme AND a similar design together, which causes an issue.